# Postgres: What could cause the error "cannot call populate_composite on a scalar"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a column of type `JSONB`, where each row contains a JSON with an array of objects, eg:

```
[
    {
        "grade": "4.44/5",
        "endYear": 2011,
        "startYear": 2006,
        "userId": "defg"
    },
    {
        "grade": "9.133/10",
        "endYear": 2010,
        "startYear": 2006,
        "userId": "abcd"
    }
]
```

I'm attempting to expand those `JSONB` collections into rows, like:

```
| grade    | startYear | endYear | userId |
-------------------------------------------
| 4.44/5   |    2006   | 2011    | defg   |
| 9.133/10 |    2006   | 2010    | abcd   |
-------------------------------------------
```

..using the following query:

```
WITH arr AS (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonbrecords) AS jsons
             FROM "table-with-jsonb"),
    lines AS (
      SELECT x.*
      FROM arr, jsonb_to_record(jsons) AS x(
                "field1" VARCHAR
                 )
  ) SELECT *
    FROM lines
```

I'm using Datagrip, which paginates results, and the query finishes fine for the first 500 rows.

However, when I try to load the last page of results, I get this error:

`[22023] ERROR: cannot call populate_composite on a scalar`

Googling this error shows almost no useful results (a first for me) except for the [Postgres source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonfuncs.c#L2702).

I don't speak C, but since the `jsonb_array_elements` CTE evaluates fine on its own, I am assuming the problem is that some row(s) have a scalar value in `jsonbrecords` column instead of a proper `JSONB`.

To ensure I had only `JSONB` values, I stripped the rows that didn't contain `'{'` with this query:

```
UPDATE  "table-with-jsonb" SET jsonbrecords = NULL
WHERE jsonbrecords :: TEXT !~ '{'
```

This deleted about a dozen rows, but the error remains.

I've also tried to find the problem by inspecting the raw `JSONB` rows in the table, but have found nothing.

Am I correct in thinking the error means a row has a non-`JSONB` value in it? If so, how can I fix? If not, how can I debug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unrelated, but: you can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT x.*
from the_table, 
     jsonb_array_elements(jsonbrecords) AS t(doc),
     jsonb_to_record(t.doc) as x ("grade" text, "userId" text, "endYear" int, "startYear" int);
```

Now for the actual question. The error can be avoided by not using `jsonb_to_record` and accessing each key individually instead:

```
SELECT t.doc ->> 'grade' as "grade",
       t.doc ->> 'endYear' as "endYear", 
       t.doc ->> 'startYear' as "startYear",
       t.doc ->> 'userId' as "userId"
from the_table, 
     jsonb_array_elements(jsonbrecords) AS t(doc);
```

You don't really lose flexibility as you need to specify the column list with `jsonb_to_record()` as well.

Online example: http://rextester.com/VVGJ34083

Answer (score 2):

I've figured this out. The problem was in a specific row of data:

```
[
    {
        "grade": "4.44/5",
        "endYear": 2011,
        "startYear": 2006,
        "userId": "defg"
    },
    {
        "grade": "9.133/10",
        "endYear": 2010,
        "startYear": 2006,
        "userId": "abcd"
    },
    null
]
```

The `null` in the end was breaking `jsonb_to_record`. Once I deleted it, everything works.

I don't know if this could happen thru normal usage, but in my case, I think this was because I wrote the data to the DB from a `nodejs` script, but accidentally set the destination column to type `TEXT` instead of type `JSONB`.

I changed the type to `JSONB` with the data already in it, so the `null` must have sneaked in that way.